# Android Gallery Selected image Size

Tags: android, gallery

I need to create an android gallery where the selected image is larger than others, how can I do it ? 
Also can I resize the image as the users drags it to give a better user experience?

Thanks

Comment: I didnt understand: the selected image is larger than others, please explain.

Comment: the default gallery shows all images with same size, I need the selected image (current image) to be larger in size

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://androidsnips.blogspot.in/2011/03/images-with-coverflow-like-animation-in.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of your requirements is a bit vague, but you could have a look at [CoverFlow](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/) and adjust it to your needs.

To zoom the image you could use [ImageViewZoom](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom).